# Bubbles Are ONly on Top of My Sourdough Starter

Tags: sourdough, starter

My starter, (new) is bubbly on top and rising but does not have may bubbles in its body.Can it still be use to make a Levin or dough?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just because the bubbles all rise to the top which is where they will sit due to the surface tension. I don't believe it is anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I agree that it's probably fine.  You should still have some tiny bubbles all throughout the starter, but you might not see them if you pop them while digging to see them.  All the big bubbles will be at the top.  If it's bubbly on top and it smells good, you should be okay to use it.